# Are H block thermostatic radiator valves universal?

Tags: plumbing, central-heating, radiator

I have bought the following radiator:
https://www.bestheating.com/milano-bow-anthracite-d-bar-central-connection-heated-towel-rail-1800mm-x-600mm-61170

However, the company supplying that radiator only appear to sell chrome valves. I would like an anthracite H block radiator valve for it, such as the following:
https://www.justradiators.co.uk/ultraheat-twin-angled-straight-thermostatic-anthracitret-valve-set

It says it's for a particular brand (Ultraheat), but are are these valves universal and can I use it with the other radiator?